# Converting uint8_t array to a char array or string in C

Tags: c, uint8t

How can I convert a uint8_t array to a char array or string in C?

```
uint8_t array[10];
```

Comment: string and char array are two different things.

Comment: Show some more code and tell us what you want to do with the char array or string once "converted".

Comment: `uint8_t` is a `typedef` alias for `unsigned char`, no "conversion" is necessary; it is a matter of interpretation.  In C a string is not a data-type.  It is a sequence of characters terminated with `'\0'`.  A `char` array is a "container" that can hold a string.  In short, your question is ambiguous.  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to cast it, assuming you system defines `char` as 8 bits:

```
char *string = (char*)array;
```

Comment: Hmmm, `string` is a pointer, not a `char` array.

Comment: Given that a) `char` is an implementation's smallest data type, b) `char` must be _at least_ 8 bits, and c) the implementation defines `uint8_t`; it is implicit that in this case `char` is 8 bits.